# AWS Cloudshell not starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudshell

I am trying to access CloudShell from my AWS account, when doing so, I receive a blank page:

[image]

I tried from the root user as well as from a user I created with the following policies:

AdministratorAccess

AWSCloudShellFullAccess

Tried different browsers, to no avail.

Comment: open plz the browser debug and see if you have no exceptions in the console

Comment: please try adding "AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore" role. Wait for few mins and check if in the connect option it allows you to open console